# esp8266 sending to both webserver and myphpadmin

Tags: esp8266, programming, arduino-ide

I have tried to send all the variables to both the webpage and to myphpadmin. I seperated
the code into two functions and put the functions inside the void loop() function under the
impression that it will loop both but it seems if I put both then the device will only send
data to phpmyadmin. However, if I delete void logs() which is the function that sends data to
phpmyadmin then the void page() which sends the data to the webpage starts working. I can't find a solution for these two functions to work together, I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, your guidance would be much appreciated

this is my code:

```
String header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
 
String html_1 = R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    body {font-size:100%;} 
    #main {display: table; margin: auto;  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; } 
    #content { border: 5px solid blue; border-radius: 15px; padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;}
    h2 {text-align:center; margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;} 
    p { text-align:center; margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 120%;}
    #time_P { margin: 10px 0px 15px 0px;}
  </style>
 
  <script> 
    function updateTime() 
    {  
       var d = new Date();
       var t = "";
       t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
       document.getElementById('P_time').innerHTML = t;
    }
 
    function updateTemp() 
    {  
       ajaxLoad('getTemp'); 
    }
 
    var ajaxRequest = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  { 
      ajaxRequest =new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else   {
      ajaxRequest =new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
      }
 
    function ajaxLoad(ajaxURL)
    {
      if(!ajaxRequest){ alert('AJAX is not supported.'); return; }
 
      ajaxRequest.open('GET',ajaxURL,true);
      ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status==200)
        {
          var ajaxResult = ajaxRequest.responseText;
          var tmpArray = ajaxResult.split("|");
          document.getElementById('Temperature').innerHTML = tmpArray[0];
          document.getElementById('Humidity').innerHTML = tmpArray[1];
          document.getElementById('Pressure').innerHTML = tmpArray[2];
          document.getElementById('Altitude').innerHTML = tmpArray[3];
        }
        
      }
      ajaxRequest.send();
    }
 
    var myVar1 = setInterval(updateTemp, 1000);  
    var myVar2 = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);  
 
  </script>
 
 
  <title>Temperature & Humidy Monitor</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
   <div id='main'>
     <h2>Temperature & Humidity Monitor</h2>
     <div id='content'> 
       <p id='P_time'>Time</p>
       <h2>Temperature</h2>
       <p> <span id='Temperature'>--</span> &#8451; </p> 
       <h2>Humidity</h2>
       <p> <span id='Humidity'>--</span> % </p>
       <h2>Pressure</h2>
       <p> <span id='Pressure'>--</span> hPs </p>
       <h2>Altitude</h2>
       <p> <span id='Altitude'>--</span> m </p>
     </div>
   </div> 
 </body>
</html>
)=====";

#ifdef ESP32
  #include <WiFi.h>
  #include <HTTPClient.h>
#else
  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
  #include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
  #include <WiFiClient.h>
#endif
#include <Wire.h>
#include "HTTPSRedirect.h"
#include "DebugMacros.h"
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <DHT.h>

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)
#define DHTPIN 2     // what digital pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11

Adafruit_BME280 bme;

const char* ssid = "fl";  // Enter SSID (WiFi Name) here
const char* password = "99110233";  //Enter Password here
const char* serverName = "http://192.168.101.17/sensordata/post-esp-data.php";
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

String apiKeyValue = "tPmAT5Ab3nnn9";
String sensorName = "BME280";
String sensorLocation = "Office";


float Temperature;
float Humidity;
float Pressure;
float Altitude;
String request = "";
int pin = 2;




void setup() {
  // initialize GPIO 2 as an output.
  pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
  
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!bme.begin(0x76)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
  

  
  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  //connect to your local wi-fi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  //check wi-fi is connected to wi-fi network
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  delay(10);
  Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected..!");
  Serial.print("Got IP: ");  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

}

void loop() {  

    
  page();
  logs();  

}



void page(){
  //sends data to webpage
  server.handleClient();

  WiFiClient client = server.client();     // Check if a client has connected
    if (!client)  {  return;  }
 
    request = client.readStringUntil('\r');     // Read the first line of the request
 
    Serial.println(request);
    Serial.println("");
 
    if ( request.indexOf("getTemp") > 0 )
     { 
          Serial.println("getTemp received");
 
          // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
         
         Temperature = bme.readTemperature();
         Pressure = bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
         Altitude = bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA);
         Humidity = bme.readHumidity();    // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
 
          if ( !isnan(Temperature) && !isnan(Humidity) && !isnan(Pressure) && !isnan(Altitude) )
          {
              client.print( header );
              client.print( Temperature );   client.print( "|" );  
              client.print( Humidity );   client.print( "|" );  
              client.print( Pressure ); client.print( "|" );  
              client.print( Altitude ); client.print( "|" );
              Serial.println("data sent");
          }
          else
          {
              Serial.println("Error reading the sensor");
          }
     }
 
     else
     {
        client.flush();
        client.print( header );
        client.print( html_1 ); 
        Serial.println("New page served");
     }
 
    delay(5);

    if (Temperature > 20.0){
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(50);               // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1);  
  }
}

void logs(){
  //sending to database
  //Check WiFi connection status
  if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
    HTTPClient http;
    
    // Takes Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
    http.begin(serverName);
    
    // Specifies content-type header
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
    // Prepare HTTP POST request data
    String httpRequestData = "api_key=" + apiKeyValue + "&sensor=" + sensorName
                          + "&location=" + sensorLocation + "&value1=" + String(bme.readTemperature())
                          + "&value2=" + String(bme.readHumidity()) + "&value3=" + String(bme.readPressure()/100.0F) + "";
    Serial.print("httpRequestData: ");
    Serial.println(httpRequestData);
    
    
    //String httpRequestData = "api_key=tPmAT5Ab3nnn9&sensor=BME280&location=Office&value1=24.75&value2=49.54&value3=1005.14";

    // Send HTTP POST request
    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData); 
        
    if (httpResponseCode>0) {
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("Error code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }
    
    http.end();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
  }
  //Send an HTTP POST request every 30 seconds
  delay(30000); 
}





void handle_OnConnect(){
  
  Temperature = bme.readTemperature();
  Pressure = bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
  Altitude = bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA);
  Humidity = bme.readHumidity();

}

void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/7613#issuecomment-700869953